# Blocking queue to replace synchronized

Tags: java

I replaced the following code with the blocking Queue below.
Why do I get a queue full exception - isn't the blocking queue expected to prevent just that?

```
    class Offer implements Runnable{
        Random r=new Random();
        public void run(){
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
                synchronized(b){
                    try{
                        while(b.size()>10){
                            b.wait();
                        }
                        b.add(r.nextInt());
                        b.notify();

                    }catch(InterruptedException x){}
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    class Take implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
                synchronized(b){
                    try{
                        while(b.size()<1){
                            b.wait();
                        }   
                        b.remove(0);
                        b.notify();


                    }catch(InterruptedException x){}
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

THe blockingqueue equivalent -

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> b = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10);
    class Offer implements Runnable{
        Random r=new Random();
        public void run(){
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
                b.add(r.nextInt());
            }
        }       
    }

    class Take implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
                b.remove(0);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You're not consuming fast enough so the queue is filling up. You need to use `put` rather than `add`. In short, RTFM.

Comment: FTFM: "`add`: Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning true upon success and throwing an IllegalStateException if no space is currently available. When using a capacity-restricted queue, it is generally preferable to use offer."

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) says `put` and `take` block. The methods  `add` and `remove` have different semantics, `add` throws an exception, `remove` returns `true`/`false` to indicate success.  RTFM.

Comment: @DaveNewton to replicate the `wait`/`notify` behaviour the blocking operations need to be used.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I know-I quoted the docs off the method the OP is using because it shows the behavior they're seeing, and provides the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `wait()` and `notify()` are blocking operations, you should use blocking operations from `BlockingQueue`: `put()` and `take()`. And as a general recommendation: *never swallow `InterruptedException`*. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/) is a good article about dealing with `InterruptedException`.

So your `BlockingQueue` replacement to `synchronized` should look like following:

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> b = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10);

class Offer implements Runnable{
    Random r=new Random();
    public void run(){
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
            try {
                b.put(r.nextInt());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Take implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
            try {
                b.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```